# Is it possible to get identical local R2 values for different regions in GWR?

Tags: geographically-weighted-regression

I am running GWR using Oshan's python code.
I tried to adapt it to a temporal variation of GWR, iterating over different months in my dataset. My study area is divided into NUTS3 regions
To extract the R2, I used this code:

```
# Extract R2 values for each NUTS3 region after GWR
r2_nuts3_dict = {}

# Iterate over each month's GWR results
for (year, month), gwr_results in gwr_results_dict.items():
    # Filter the GeoDataFrame for the corresponding month
    gdf_month = gdf[(gdf['date'].dt.year == year) & (gdf['date'].dt.month == month)]

    # Ensure the GeoDataFrame is not empty
    if not gdf_month.empty:
        # Retrieve the R2 values from the GWR results
        local_r2 = gwr_results.localR2

        # Match the R2 values to the NUTS3 codes, ensuring alignment
        for i, r2_value in enumerate(local_r2):
            nuts3_code = gdf_month.iloc[i]['NUTS3']  # Get the NUTS3 code for the corresponding row
            r2_nuts3_dict[(nuts3_code, year, month)] = r2_value
```

And then when I tried to access and plot as time series the R2 values for different big cities such as Berlin, Munich, Hamburg and Frankfurt, the graphs are the same for Berlin, Hamburg and Frankfurt (these two have the same values even) and it only varies for Munich.

I don't understand what's happening.